# Unable to use conditional regex to test my string in python

Tags: python, regex

I would like to write a regex to fulfil following requirements:

| Test case | Test string | Is Valid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `board add 0/1 aaa` | True |
| 2 | `board add 0/1 xxx` | False |
| 3 | `EMPTY_STRING` | True |
| 4 |  | True |
| 5 | `board add 0/2 aaa` | True |

Then, I decided to build the regex with python by make use of

`(?(xxx)YES-PATTERN|NO-PATTERN)`

I come up with following

- `(board add 0/1)?(?(1) (aaa|bbb))`

  - If `(board add 0/1)` exists, we check whether it follows  `aaa` or  `bbb`
  - If `(board add 0/1)` does not exists, we make it pass

But, the regex above just does not work as expected. It failed on test case 2. Anyone know how to fix it?

You can check my regex by following url

https://regex101.com/r/M8UEsb/1

Comment: Just use `'xxx' not in string`

Comment: No offence... I would like to code in regex. If not possible, I will write something else

Comment: You could also try `^(?!.*\bboard add 0/1 (?!aaa|bbb)).*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not matching the 2 in example nr. 5, only the 1.

But as the group 1 value is optional, and you only test for group 1 in the if/else clause, it can match at any position and the pattern is also unanchored.

---

You could also write an alternation that allows all the patterns instead of using if/else:

```
^[^\S\n]*(?:board add 0/[12] (?:aaa|bbb))?$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `[^\S\n]*` Mach optional spaces without newlines
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `board add 0/[12]`  Match the string ending on either 1 or 2
  - `(?:aaa|bbb)` Match one of the alternatives
- `)?` Close the group
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9L4xWG/1)

Example

```
import re

strings = ["board add 0/1 aaa", "board add 0/1 xxx", "", "    ", "board add 0/2 aaa"]

for s in strings:
    m = re.match(r"^[^\S\n]*(?:board add 0/[12] (?:aaa|bbb))?$", s)
    print(f"'{s}' ==> {bool(m)}")
```

Output

```
'board add 0/1 aaa' ==> True
'board add 0/1 xxx' ==> False
'' ==> True
'    ' ==> True
'board add 0/2 aaa' ==> True
```

Comment: Why we need `^` & `$` for this case?

Comment: @MondWan Only if you want to match the whole line. You can omit it if you want but then you can get partial matches. See https://regex101.com/r/xgmKKw/1

Comment: But without them, the regex does not pass test case 2

Comment: @MondWan The you can either make it `^\s*(?:board add 0/[12] (?:aaa|bbb|xxx)|\s*)$` https://regex101.com/r/NJXhwD/1 or more global `^\s*(?:board add 0/[12] [a-z]{3}|\s*)$` https://regex101.com/r/oHNSKC/1

Comment: They are still not passing test case 2.

Comment: @MondWan Should it match `board add 0/1 xxx` ? Or should it not match?

Comment: The regex should fail the string `board add 0/1 xxx`.

Comment: @MondWan The pattern in the answer does not match that string, see https://regex101.com/r/9L4xWG/1

Comment: Only the 1st answer https://regex101.com/r/9L4xWG/1  from you works

Comment: @MondWan Yes, the text in the beginning is an explanation why it does not work.

Comment: @MondWan you could do something along this using the if / else `(^[^\S\n]*board add 0/[12])?(?(1) (aaa|bbb)|^[^\S\n]*$)` but it would be longer and more difficult to read https://regex101.com/r/3I63jS/1

Answer (score 1):

This pattern checks the existence of `aaa` or `bbb` if the string starts with `board add 0/1` or `board add 0/2`. And if any of `board add 0/1` and `board add 0/2` does not exist, it passes.

```
^(?:(?!board add 0/[12]).)*$|board add 0/[12] (?:aaa|bbb)
```

##### Regex Explanation

- `^` Start of a string
- `(?:` Non-capturing group

  - `(?!` Negative lookahead assertion - assert that the following regex does not match

    - `board add 0/[12]` Match `board add 0/1` or `board add 0/2`
  - `)` Close lookahead
  - `.` Any character except newline
- `)` Close non-capturing group
- `*` The previous match can be matched zero or more times
- `$` End of a string
- `|` OR. If the whole previous pattern did not match then check the next
- `board add 0/[12]`  Match `board add 0/1`  or `board add 0/2`
- `(?:` Non-capturing group

  - `aaa|bbb` Match `aaa` or `bbb`
- `)` Close non-capturing group

See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/5xvjxR/1)

##### Python Example

```
import re

strings = [
    'board add 0/1 aaa',
    'board add 0/1 xxx',
    '',
    '                 ',
    'board add 0/2 aaa'
]

for string in strings:
    print(bool(re.match(r'^(?:(?!board add 0/[12]).)*$|board add 0/[12] (?:aaa|bbb)', string)))
```

##### Output

```
True
False
True
True
True
```