# conditional regex on multiline string in python

Tags: python, regex

This question is similar to my original post.

[Unable to use conditional regex to test my string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72564305/unable-to-use-conditional-regex-to-test-my-string-in-python/72564359?noredirect=1#comment128183595_72564359)

The reason for posting another new question is that the requirement here is a little different than the original one.

If the given string is a line by line based, the original answer is good enough. But, the answer there cannot cover the case on multiline string. See below

| Test case | Test string | Expect value from bool(re.match(...)) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1. Naive match | ``` xxxx xxxx board add 0/1 aaa board add 0/2 aaa board add 0/3 bbb board add 0/4 bbb board add 0/5 aaa # ``` | True |
| 2. Bad model name | ``` xxxx xxxx board add 0/1 xxx board add 0/2 aaa board add 0/3 bbb board add 0/4 aaa board add 0/5 bbb # ``` | False |
| 3. Missing model | ``` xxxx xxxx board add 0/2 aaa board add 0/3 bbb board add 0/4 bbb board add 0/5 aaa # ``` | True |

I try multiple regex. But, all of them fail on either test case (2) / (3).

| Tried Regex | Failed on Test |
| --- | --- |
| `(board add 0/1)? (?(1) (aaa|bbb))` | 2 |
| `^(?:(?!board add 0/1).)*$|board add 0/1 (?:aaa|bbb)` | 2 |
| `board add 0/1 (aaa|bbb)` | 3 |
| `(?=board add 0/1 )(?:board add 0/1 (aaa|bbb))` | 3 |

Is it possible to write a regex for getting above test case pass?

You can check them on following url

https://regex101.com/r/2l2Qd4/1

NOTE:

- I just want to catch a particular `board add 0/1` instead of `board add 0/\d+`

  - In my actual use case, interfaces may need different models. That's why I am trying to figure out a particular regex for `board add 0/1`. Then, I can extend the regex to `board add 0/2` to `board add 0/21` one by one
- Requirements of a valid string

  - If `board add 0/1` exists in the string, it must be followed by `(aaa|bbb)`. Otherwise, it is invalid
  - If `board add 0/1` does not exists in the string, this is a valid string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, you can use this regex

```
board add 0/\d+ (?!aaa|bbb)
```

If the regex matches then the string is invalid.

##### Python Example

```
import re


strings = [
    """xxxx
xxxx
 board add 0/1 aaa
 board add 0/2 aaa
 board add 0/3 bbb
 board add 0/4 bbb
 board add 0/5 aaa
#""",
    """xxxx
xxxx
 board add 0/1 xxx
 board add 0/2 aaa
 board add 0/3 bbb
 board add 0/4 aaa
 board add 0/5 bbb
#""",
    """xxxx
xxxx
 board add 0/2 aaa
 board add 0/3 bbb
 board add 0/4 bbb
 board add 0/5 aaa
#"""
]

for string in strings:
    print(not bool(re.search(r"board add 0/\d+ (?!aaa|bbb)", string)))
```

##### Output

```
True
False
True
```

##### Explanation

`re.search` returns the matched chunk of the string by the given pattern. If any matching does not exist returns `None`. The solution is based on negating the valid strings. So if neither `aaa` nor `bbb` is followed after `board add 0/1` then the string is invalid. The rest are passed as you described in your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72564305/unable-to-use-conditional-regex-to-test-my-string-in-python/72564359?noredirect=1). So, if the `re.search` returns any value but `None`, then the `not bool(...)` will convert the value to the expected result.

**NOTE:** I'm using `not bool(...)` as the string is valid if it does not contain the pattern.

> We can just focus on board add 0/1 and ignoring other board add 0/x in this question. In fact, despite the negation, your current solution fits my need. I am just wondering why we need negation, and why my answer does not work.

The first `(board add 0/1)? (?(1) (aaa|bbb))` I cannot understand what did you expect to match. The second regex is similar to my answer to your previous question. The third one is more close to the answer.

I changed the regex I was suggesting to your previous question.

```
^(?:(?!board add 0\/1).)*$|^.*?board add 0\/1 (?:aaa|bbb).*$
```

Now you can use `re.match` instead of `re.search`

```
...

for string in strings:
    print(bool(re.match(r"^(?:(?!board add 0\/1).)*$|^.*?board add 0\/1 (?:aaa|bbb).*$", string, re.S)))
```

##### Output

```
True
False
True
```

**NOTE:** There also used the `re.S` (singleline) flag.

Comment: I am not sure why `re.search` gives you this result. But, regex101 shows that your answer cannot pass the tests I wrote

Comment: @MondWan, I have added an explanation.

Comment: Ah.. I finally got the idea. But, why we need negation to tackle this problem? Would you mind to explain why regex like `(board add 0/1)? (?(1) (aaa|bbb))` does not work as first placed?

Comment: 2ndly, I tried to negate your regex by `(?!board add 0/\d+ (?!aaa|bbb))`. But, it failed. Why it is not possible to do that?

Comment: Why are you trying to negate my regex? Maybe to not use `not bool(...)` but just `re.match`?

Comment: The main reason is that I am just trying to put every logic into the regex if possible. The 2nd reason is that I just want to know why it does not work at the first place due to curiosity.

Comment: Could you list the conditions that describe a valid string?

Comment: Sure. I have updated my question. The requirements are listed at the end of the question.

Comment: So `board add 0/2` can be followed with `abc` but `board add 0/1` should only be followed by `aaa` or `bbb`?

Comment: Yes. But, generally, we can just focus on `board add 0/1` and ignoring other `board add 0/x` in this question. In fact, despite the negation, your current solution fits my need. I am just wondering why we need negation, and why my answer does not work.

Comment: Please check my edit

Comment: @MondWan, Did you try `^(?:(?!board add 0\/1).)*$|^.*?board add 0\/1 (?:aaa|bbb).*$`?

Comment: Yea. I can make it work after enabling `re.S`. But, I decided to use the negation one. It is much simpler for fixing my case. Thanks for the explanations & answers

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want to match all board lines ending with either aaa or bbb, and being indented between strings that start the line with a non whitespace character.

To prevent partial matches, you would need to identify the part before and after the repeating board part.

```
^\S.*(?:\n[^\S\n]+board add 0/\d+ (?:aaa|bbb))+\n\S
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `\S.*` Match a non whitespace char and the rest of the line
- `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole part

  - `\n[^\S\n]+` Match a newline followed by 1+ spaces
  - `board add 0/\d+ (?:aaa|bbb)` Match the board pattern where `\d+` matches 1+ digits
- `)+` Close the non capture group and repeat 1+ times to match at least a single line
- `\n\S` Match a newline and a non whitespace char

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y3crAh/1)

Comment: Sorry for missing requirements in the question. I have updated my question's requirement a bit. I need to catch `board add 0/1` specifically. I tried to change `\d+` with `1` therefore. But, it does not work as expected. Recently, only answer from @ArtyomVancyan sort of fulfil what I need.

Comment: @MondWan You could scan all the lines and check if there is no occurrence `board add 0/1 ` that is not followed by either aaa or bbb using `re.S` to have the dot match a newline like `^(?!.*\bboard add 0/1 (?!aaa|bbb)).+` See https://regex101.com/r/HRhhRM/1 and  https://regex101.com/r/LPKD2m/1

Comment: Got it. It looks like the flag `re.S` is important in my case. Without this, I just cannot make it right. But, I pick the answer from @ArtyomVancyan since the negation one is  simpler.

Comment: @MondWan That is perfectly ok :-)  good luck!